# Issues loading System.ObjectModel when using TypeConverterAttribute in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, typeconverter

Switching from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.0 should be a breeze. However, I run into issues when using the `TypeConverterAttribute`. When using .NET Core 3.0, I get this runtime error when accessing an enumeration that is decorated with the `TypeConverterAttribute`:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
>   'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute' from assembly
>   'System.ObjectModel, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'

[image]

When I switch back to .NET Core 2.2, the problem is resolved.

This issue is persistent no matter which version of *Microsoft.NETCore.App* I refer to.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have a feeling this is related to breaking changes in [.NET Core 2.2 to 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0) but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: OMG, thanks for this link. Further down on that page, it explains the issue which sounds like this is the problem. I'll be checking this later this week. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0#typedescriptionproviderattribute-moved-to-another-assembly

Comment: No worries, a really helpful GitHub repo to follow / watch is the [aspnet/Announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements) repo. You'll get emails on breaking changes like this or security issues.